ebproof Proof Trees: Side conditions overlapping
I am using the ebproof package to make derivation trees for inference rules. These rules have premises above the judgement, and side conditions on the left:

To generate this, I use:
   \begin{prooftree*}
        \hypo{\Gamma \vdash \triple{P'}{S}{Q'}}
        \infer[left label=
            $\begin{array}{r}
            Q' \geq 0 \\
            P \geq P' \\
            Q \leq Q'
            \end{array}$]
            1[\textsc{(While)}]
            { \Gamma \vdash  \triple{P}{while $e$ do $S$}{Q} }
    \end{prooftree*}


However, I am having a problem whereby the side conditions overlap with surrounding elements. Where there is a single inference, I can just put \vspace{...} before and after the prooftree, but where there is another inference (i.e. as part of a larger tree), this doesn't work (\vspace{...} is ignored inside the prooftree environment).

(Code to generate this:)
    \begin{prooftree}
        \hypo{\Gamma \vdash \triple{P}{$S_1$}{Q_1}}
        \hypo{\Gamma \vdash \triple{P}{$S_2$}{Q_2}}
        \infer[left label={
            $\begin{array}{r}
            Q' \leq Q_1 \\
            Q' \leq Q_2
            \end{array}$}]
            2[\textsc{(B-Cond)}]
            { \Gamma \vdash  \triple{P}{if $e$ then $S_1$ else $S_2$}{Q} }
        \infer
        [left label={$
        \begin{array}{r}
            P \geq Q' \\
            Q \leq Q'
        \end{array}
        $}]
        1[\textsc{(B-Conseq)}]
        {\Gamma \vdash \triple{P}{if $e$ then $S_1$ else $S_2$}{Q}}
    \end{prooftree}

Is there a clean way to make it have the correct amount of space? Using the array environment is a bit hacky, but it was the only way that I could add line-breaks to the left-label parameter in \infer. Alternatively, are there any other packages that provide this syntax in a cleaner way?

This isn't relevant to the problem, but if you want to copy these code snippets into your own document exactly, here is the definition of \triple: \newcommand{\triple}[3]{ \{#1\}\ \texttt{#2}\ \{#3\}}

Please, add also the code for the second picture.

Added, Thanks for the reminder, @egreg!

The code doesn't compile. Please fix it and also provide a definition for \triple.

Definition for triple is at the end of the post! Should compile with that, it also does of course need the ebproof package. Thanks for trying to help! @egreg

I see two possibilities.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\newcommand{\triple}[3]{\{#1\}\ \texttt{#2}\ \{#3\}}
\newcommand{\bstrutb}{\smash[t]{\vphantom{\bigg|}}}
\newcommand{\bstrutt}{\smash[b]{\vphantom{\bigg|}}}
\newcommand{\bstrut}{\vphantom{\bigg|}}

\begin{document}

\section{Spacing the lines}

\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{\bstrutb \Gamma \vdash \triple{P}{$S_1$}{Q_1}}
    \hypo{\Gamma \vdash \triple{P}{$S_2$}{Q_2}}
    \infer[left label={
        $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
        Q' \leq Q_1 \\
        Q' \leq Q_2
        \end{array}$}]
        2[\textsc{(B-Cond)}]
        {\bstrut \Gamma \vdash  \triple{P}{if $e$ then $S_1$ else $S_2$}{Q} }
    \infer
    [left label={
        $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
        P \geq Q' \\
        Q \leq Q'
        \end{array}$}]
    1[\textsc{(B-Conseq)}]
    {\bstrutt \Gamma \vdash \triple{P}{if $e$ then $S_1$ else $S_2$}{Q}}
\end{prooftree}

\section{Reducing the size, with some more space}

\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{\Gamma \vdash \triple{P}{$S_1$}{Q_1}}
    \hypo{\Gamma \vdash \triple{P}{$S_2$}{Q_2}}
    \infer[left label={
        $\substack{
        Q' \leq Q_1 \\
        Q' \leq Q_2
        }$}]
        2[\textsc{(B-Cond)}]
        {\vphantom{\Big|}\Gamma \vdash  \triple{P}{if $e$ then $S_1$ else $S_2$}{Q} }
    \infer
    [left label={
        $\substack{
        P \geq Q' \\
        Q \leq Q'
        }$}]
    1[\textsc{(B-Conseq)}]
    {\Gamma \vdash \triple{P}{if $e$ then $S_1$ else $S_2$}{Q}}
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}


The additional spaces are obtained with a hack, actually.
With \smash[t]{\vphantom{\bigg|}} I insert the lower part of a \bigg| (without printing the symbol), because \smash[t]{...} takes care of disregarding the symbol's heigh. This is useful for the top line, so I call it a “bottom strut”.
Similarly with `\smash[b]{\vphantom{\bigg|}}, a “top strut” useful for the bottom line (the depth, that is, what's below the baseline) is disregarded.
The full strut is useful for the middle line: neither the height nor the depth are disregarded.
In the second display, a shorter strut is used, but the idea is the same.

Thank you, this seems to work. Might you be able to offer some explanation as to how the extra space works? I don't quite understand what it does, so am not sure how to use the new commands you've created when I have longer proof trees, or more side conditions.

@M.SalmanKhan I added a few comments.

Thank you for the explanation! I see, so you're just adding space above/below the line? Is there a way to make this work if I have more side conditions? I expect to have some trees that end in very long lists of side conditions.... It seems like I can't stack these to add more space, and I also can't add too much space between the hypotheses and judgements or it will no longer read properly...

@M.SalmanKhan I believe you aren't using the best way for presenting your ideas, then. Sorry, but what else you think to do other than making the side conditions so tiny that they cannot be read?

@M.SalmanKhan When you say they end in very long lists ... do the side constraints apply to the tree as a whole or to particular inferences? What do you actually want the result to look like or how are these usually done? Maybe they just don't fit the pattern of proofs ebproof is designed for. Side constraint sounds more like another premise than anything. The spaces at the sides are only designed for justifications (rule name etc.) or labels (for later reference) or maybe something like variable substitution, where you're introducing a name.
